# Bluetooth doesnt turn on until I do this

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth

My Bluetooth stopped turning on using the switch shown here, possibly after an update was installed for my Ubuntu 22.04 system.

[image]

The only way to get it working again is to run the commands:

```
sudo rmmod btusb
sleep 1
sudo modprobe btusb
```

What is the underlying problem? Is there a real fix for this? Otherwise I have to run these commands whenever the machine is restarted.

### Some system statuses when there's problem enabling Bluetooth

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[    4.487740] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.487800] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    4.487802] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.487816] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.487819] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.487827] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    6.628034] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version command failed (-110)
[   10.809354] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   10.809357] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   10.809359] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

```
$ systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2023-08-05 17:15:01 EDT; 2min 54s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 51746 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 154392)
     Memory: 688.0K
        CPU: 78ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─51746 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Aug 05 17:15:01 z-pc systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Aug 05 17:15:01 z-pc bluetoothd[51746]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
Aug 05 17:15:01 z-pc systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Aug 05 17:15:01 z-pc bluetoothd[51746]: Starting SDP server
Aug 05 17:15:01 z-pc bluetoothd[51746]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
```

```
$ sudo rfkill 
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
 1 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
```